# Auth.currentSession says no current user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have basic react app where I am trying to have auth using aws-amplify. 
I have a user pool set up in cognito. I am able to send the user to the hosted ui. The user is able to log in, but when I try to get the current session, I get a message saying `no current user`.

Here is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsmobile from "./aws-exports";

const auth = {
  AppWebDomain: "funnybusty.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com",
  TokenScopesArray: ["phone", "email", "profile", "openid", "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"],
  RedirectUriSignIn: "http://localhost:3000",
  RedirectUriSignOut: "http://localhost:3000",
  responseType: "token",
  ClientId: "aaaaa",
  UserPoolId: "aaaa",
};

Amplify.configure(awsmobile);
Auth.configure({ oauth: auth });

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    Auth.currentSession()
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  click = () => {
    const config = Auth.configure().oauth
    const url = 'https://' + config.AppWebDomain + '/login?redirect_uri=' + config.RedirectUriSignIn + '&response_type=' + config.responseType + '&client_id=' + config.ClientId;
    window.location.assign(url);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.click}>
          Sign in with AWS
          </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I never used reactjs but I noticed few things:

1. You have to use the **Hub module** to listen on the `signIn` event. Otherwise, you cannot get back your user information.
2. In your **oauth configuration**, you have to define your `redirectSignIn` and `redirectSignOut` with **http://localhost:3000/** (the `/` at the end is important, I learnt it the hard way..)
3. You probably have to move `ClientId` and `UserPoolId` out of your **const auth** as the pattern of the oauth configuration is:

   ```
   const oauth = {
     domain: 'your_cognito_domain',
     scope: ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
     redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000/',
     redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000/',
     responseType: 'code' // or token
   };
   ```

For more information, you can check the full example available on the documentation: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#make-it-work-in-your-app

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a subtle mistake in my code. This line,

```
Auth.configure({ oauth: auth });
```

Should really look like this.

```
Auth.configure({
    Auth: {
      oauth: auth,
    }
  })
```

The docs are not too clear about this, so I want to leave this here for future googlers.

I was following the docs as I saw [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#make-it-work-in-your-app), but the docs do also mention the correct way [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#configuring-the-hosted-ui).

I am not sure if this is some kind of mistake in the docs, but it sure was confusing. Hopefully this helps others.

Comment: links are broken

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I will answer for the other people that will have this issue.

I read that calling `Auth.currentSession()` in `componentDidMount()` is not really a good practice. Try to call it in an async function and putting `await` before `Auth.currentSession()`.

Example :

```
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react'
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
Amplify.configure(aws_exports);

class App extends Component {
  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            postId: null
        };
    }

async example() {

    
        let user = await Auth.currentSession().then(data => 
        console.log(data));
    

  }


render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
                <h5 className="card-header">Simple POST Request</h5>
                <div className="card-body">

                </div>

                <button onClick={this.example}>
            Req1!
            </button>

            </div>


        );
    }
}
```